# How much memory does Maven know to use?

Tags: maven, memory, jenkins, maven-3

We're using Maven 3.3 with Jenkins on an Amazon Linux machine with 4 GB memory.  We have MAVEN_OPTS set to

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Notice there is no "-mx" parameter.  We start the containing Jenkins instance with this command ...

```
/usr/bin/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx4096m -DJENKINS_HOME=/home/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
```

Yet when our builds finish, we typically get a memory line that looks like

```
[INFO] Final Memory: 75M/1237M
```

Since we have not specified a MAVEN_OPTS memory argument, how does Maven know how much memory to use?

Comment: Which version of Maven do you use? Maven 3.3. does not exist ? Do you mean Maven 3.3.9 or Maven 3.3.1 ? Apart from that the used JVM calculate a default value (If i correctly remember 1/4 of the physical size)...Apart from that are you using that in Maven Job type in Jenkins ? Or a freestyle job or a pipeline ?

Comment: Its a Maven job (as opposed to a freestyle one).  If you're 1/4 theory were correct, wouldn't that mean final memory would be less than 1024M?  Our "Final memory" consistently shows a number greater than that.

Comment: You have written a machine with 4 GB which means physical memory ? Does you machine has exactly 4 GiB or a little bit more? Furthermore your settings for Jenkins can't be ok if you have a machine with 4 GB memory, cause the size of -Xmx + size of MaxPermIsze is more than 4 GiB. Apart from that the OS takes some memory...So you are running on JDK 7 ?

Comment: Yes, it is JDK 7 and yes I'm talking about physical memory.  How do my settings not being correct affect your 1/4 theory?  Also is that documented somewhere, as I'm having trouble finding that in the Maven documentation.

Comment: That is JVM part not Maven part...means Oracle JDK documentation.